# LIKE query on values of Map ElementCollection in entity in HQL

Tags: orm, hql, sql-like

I have an entity named « Form » that contains a Map « details » of (key/value)=(language code/translation) :

```
@Entity
class Form {
:
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "language", length = 50, nullable = false)
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "value", length = 150)
private final Map<Language, String> details = new HashMap<Language, String>  ();
```

:
}

I would like to retrieve all Form records having a translation containing (!) « xxx ».

The following clause retrieves « Form » where the map contains a « value » whose value is exactly equals the search stream. I would like however apply a LIKE condition.

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Form f JOIN f.details d WHERE KEY(d) = :language AND :search IN elements(d) ")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean in your `WHERE` clause, i.e. `WHERE ... AND x IN y AND a LIKE b`?

Comment: I want to do something like : `@Query("SELECT f FROM Form f JOIN f.details d WHERE KEY(d) = :language AND VALUE(d) LIKE :search ") `

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, `%` is a wildcard used in the `LIKE` operator. Your query would be something like:

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Form f JOIN f.details d 
WHERE KEY(d) = :language 
AND VALUE(d) LIKE '%' + :search + '%'")
```

If this doesn't work, you might have to append `%` to the beginning and end of you variable `:search`